# How to get an attribute of an Element that is namespaced

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I'm parsing an XML document that I receive from a vendor everyday and it uses namespaces heavily. I've minimized the problem to a minimal subset here:

There are some elements I need to parse, all of which are children of an element with a specific attribute in it.
I am able to use `lxml.etree.Element.findall(TAG, root.nsmap)` to find the candidate nodes whose attribute I need to check.

I'm then trying to check the attribute of each of these `Elements` via the name I know it uses : which concretely here is `ss:Name`. If the value of that attribute is the desired value I'm going to dive deeper into said `Element` (to continue doing other things).

How can I do this?

The XML I'm parsing is roughly

```
<FOO xmlns="SOME_REALLY_LONG_STRING"
 some gorp declaring a bunch of namespaces one of which is 
 xmlns:ss="THE_VERY_SAME_REALLY_LONG_STRING_AS_ROOT"
>
    <child_of_foo>
        ....
    </child_of_foo>
    ...
    <SomethingIWant ss:Name="bar" OTHER_ATTRIBS_I_DONT_CARE_ABOUT>
        ....
        <MoreThingsToLookAtLater>
            ....
        </MoreThingsToLookAtLater>
        ....
    </SomethingIWant>
    ...
</FOO>
```

I found the first Element I wanted `SomethingIWant` like so (ultimately I want them all so I did find all)

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(myfilename)
root = tree.getroot()
# i want just the first one for now
my_sheet = root.findall('ss:RecordSet', root.nsmap)[0]
```

Now I want to get the `ss:Name` attribute from this element, to check it, but I'm not sure how?

I know that `my_sheet.attrib` will display me the raw URI followed by the attribute name, but I don't want that. I need to check if it has a specific value for a specific namespaced attribute. (Because if it's wrong I can skip this element from further processing entirely).

I tried using `lxml.etree.ElementTree.attrib.get()` but I don't seem to obtain anything useful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you actually using `lxml` library or only xml parser from standard python? What is `etree` exactly, `lxml.etree`?

Comment: updated again based on @har07 answer

Comment: So you want to get attribute in namespace from previously selected element, say `my_sheet` in your code snippet. In this case, my update is relevant to your updated question.

Comment: You can even select all elements having certain attribute equals certain value in one xpath expression, if you like. Something like : `root.xpath('//ss:RecordSet[@ss:Name="bar"]')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of advantages of `lxml` over standard python XML parser is `lxml`'s full-support of XPath 1.0 specfication via `xpath()` method. So I would go with `xpath()` method most of the time. Working example for your current case :

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """<FOO xmlns="SOME_REALLY_LONG_STRING"
 xmlns:ss="THE_VERY_SAME_REALLY_LONG_STRING_AS_ROOT"
>
    <child_of_foo>
        ....
    </child_of_foo>
    ...
    <SomethingIWant ss:Name="bar">
        ....
    </SomethingIWant>
    ...
</FOO>"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
ns = {'ss': 'THE_VERY_SAME_REALLY_LONG_STRING_AS_ROOT'}

# i want just the first one for now
result = root.xpath('//@ss:Name', namespaces=ns)[0]
print(result)
```

**output :**

```
bar
```

**UPDATE :**

Modified example demonstrating how to get attribute in namespace from current `element` :

```
ns = {'ss': 'THE_VERY_SAME_REALLY_LONG_STRING_AS_ROOT', 'd': 'SOME_REALLY_LONG_STRING'}

element = root.xpath('//d:SomethingIWant', namespaces=ns)[0]
print(etree.tostring(element))

attribute = element.xpath('@ss:Name', namespaces=ns)[0]
print(attribute)
```

**output :**

```
<SomethingIWant xmlns="SOME_REALLY_LONG_STRING" xmlns:ss="THE_VERY_SAME_REALLY_LONG_STRING_AS_ROOT" ss:Name="bar">
        ....
    </SomethingIWant>
    ...

bar
```

Comment: Thanks very helpful!  That looks immensely more correct however there is a subtlety I didn't clarify enough that I'm updating question for.. If that `result` is what I am looking for, I am going to need a reference to that element as a whole because it means it has children I have to process. Updating the question to emphasize that; my fault.

Comment: Updated my answer to shows how to use `xpath()` to get both the attribute and it's parent element. Hope I understand your requirement correctly

Comment: The only wrinkle is that the URI for `d` is literally that for `ss` and so they never actually use `d` ; But i think i can actually use `ss` for that one... either way this only simplifies what you gave me; which is perfect!  Thanks again

Comment: When i try this using nsmap = root.nsmap and pass namespaces=nsmap i always get an error of empty namespace prefix is not supported in XPath.. because there is an entry for key None that points to same value as key 'ss'

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure this is a horribly NON-PYTHONIC non ideal way to do it; and it seems like there must be a better way... but I discovered I could do this:

`SS_REAL = "{%s}" % root.nsmap.get('ss')`

and then I could do:
`my_sheet.get( SS_REAL + "NAME" )`

It gets me what I want.. but this can't possibly be the *right* way to do this..

Comment: This is a dirty way of doing but to keep the show running this is helpful.

Comment: I know, hence my first line and not accepting my own answer as an answer; this was to show a way I discovered after asking the question

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

https://pastebin.com/F5HAw6zQ

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sys import argv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

NS = 'x' # default namespace key # (any string is OK)

class XMLParser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ns = {}     # namespace dict
        self.root = None # XML's root element

    # extracts the namespace (usually from the root element)
    def get_namespace(self, tag):
        return tag.split('}')[0][1:]

    # loads the XML file (here: from string)
    def load_xml(self, xmlstring):
        root = ET.fromstring(xmlstring)
        self.root = root
        self.ns[NS] = self.get_namespace(root.tag)
        return True

    # transforms XPath without namespaces to XPath with namespace
    # AND detects if last element is an attribute
    def ns_xpath(self, xpath):
        tags = xpath.split('/')
        if tags[-1].startswith('@'):
            attrib = tags.pop()[1:]
        else:
            attrib = None
        nsxpath = '/'.join(['%s:%s' % (NS, tag) for tag in tags])
        return nsxpath, attrib

    # `find` and `findall` method in one place honoring attributes in XPath
    def xfind(self, xpath, e=None, findall=False):
        if not e:
            e = self.root
        if not findall:
            f = e.find
        else:
            f = e.findall
        nsxpath, attrib = self.ns_xpath(xpath)
        e = f(nsxpath, self.ns)
        if attrib:
            return e.get(attrib)
        return e

def main(xmlstring):
    p = XMLParser()
    p.load_xml(xmlstring)
    xpaths = {
        'Element a:': 'a',
        'Element b:': 'a/b',
        'Attribute c:': 'a/b/@c'
        }
    for key, xpath in xpaths.items():
        print key, xpath, p.xfind(xpath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xmlstring = """<root xmlns="http://www.example.com">
        <a>
            <b c="Hello, world!">
            </b>
        </a>
    </root>"""
    main(xmlstring)
```

Result:

```
Element a: a <Element '{http://www.example.com}a' at 0x2bbcb30>
Element b: a/b <Element '{http://www.example.com}b' at 0x2bbcb70>
Attribute c: a/b/@c Hello, world!
```