# How to select multiple attributes for XPath query

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I select multiple sets of attributes within an XML document using XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303970/how-do-i-select-multiple-sets-of-attributes-within-an-xml-document-using-xpath)

My HTML code:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
```

i want to select this table by specifying not only the width but also with cellpadding and cellspacing..

I am using this PHP code:

```
$query = $xpath->query('//table[@width|@cellpadding|@cellspacing]');
```

but it still displays the whole html source instead of what i want..
help me please..

Comment: actually i saw it already but it does not qork on my case..maybe i dont know how to make it in html..im new to use xpath..i need help:| thanks for response

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like you do not want  to select the attributes, but check if all of the attributes are there. I.e.:

```
    $query = $xpath->query('//table[@width and @cellpadding and @cellspacing]');
```

Or if you want specifically the table, check the attributes for certain values?

```
    $query = $xpath->query('//table[@width = "100%" and @cellpadding = "6" and @cellspacing = "0"]');
```