# PHP XPath - Select one specific node and his parent node with one rule

Tags: php, xpath

I'm working on parsing some XML files using Xpath. I want to select one specific Category node and his parent node (Sport) with one expression?!

**XML document: livescore_full.xml**

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<LivescoreData generatedAt="2013-08-18T09:41:19 CEST" type="full">
    <Sport SportId="1">
        <Name language="en">Soccer</Name>
        <Category CategoryId="48">
            <Name language="en">Argentina</Name>
            <Tournament TournamentId="68" UniqueTournamentId="155">
                <Name language="en">Primera Division, Torneo Inicial</Name>
            </Tournament>
        </Category>
        <Category CategoryId="49">
            <Name language="en">Brazil</Name>
            <Tournament TournamentId="69" UniqueTournamentId="156">
                <Name language="en">Brazil Primera Division</Name>
            </Tournament>
        </Category>
    </Sport>
    <Sport SportId="2">
        <Name language="en">Basketball</Name>
        <Category CategoryId="55">
            <Name language="en">Spain</Name>
            <Tournament TournamentId="545" UniqueTournamentId="453">
                <Name language="en">Primera Division, Torneo Inicial</Name>
            </Tournament>
        </Category>
        <Category CategoryId="56">
            <Name language="en">England</Name>
            <Tournament TournamentId="654" UniqueTournamentId="5656">
                <Name language="en">England</Name>
            </Tournament>
        </Category>
    </Sport>
</LivescoreData>


 $xml = simplexml_load_file("livescore_full.xml");
 $data = $xml->xpath('//Category[@CategoryId="48"]'); 
 print_r($data); // only return data for specific Category node
```

*$data* contains data about Category node id=48, but there is no information about the sport id and sport name.

How to write Xpath rule to select Sport and Category data using CategoryId attribute? I tried some variations with the *ancestor-or-self*, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

```
"/LiveScoreData/Sport[Category[@CategoryId='48']"
```

Would be one way.

Comment: With "/LiveScoreData/Sport[Category[@CategoryId='48']]" is returned empty array. With "//Sport[Category[@CategoryId='48']]" is returned Sport node, and both Category nodes (48 i 49), but only categoryid 48 is required.

And thank you for prompt answer.

Comment: Xpath selects nodes, it doesn't manipulate them. once you have it, you could remove the ones with the id's you don't want

Answer (score 0):

One easy answer which comes to mind is ([*How do I select multiple nodesets*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303970/how-do-i-select-multiple-sets-of-attributes-within-an-xml-document-using-xpath)):

```
$data = $xml->xpath('//Category[@CategoryId="48"] | //Sport[Category[@CategoryId="48"]]');
```

However, I'd drop SimpleXML for this case and do this:

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->load("livescore_full.xml");
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
 $category = $xpath->query('//Category[@CategoryId="48"]')->item(0);
 //then sport is just it's parentNode:
 $sport = $category->parentNode;
```

---

```
 //removing all other cats:
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->load("livescore_full.xml");
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

 $categories = $xpath->query('//Sport[Category[@CategoryId="48"]]/Category[@CategoryId!="48"]');
 while($othercat = $categories->item(0)){
     $othercat->parentNode->removeChild($othercat);
 }
```

Comment: Selecting multiple nodes is not the solution  I'm looking for.

I'm try to get result like this (array of objects in that structure): 

`<Sport SportId="1">
        <Name language="en">Soccer</Name>
        <Category CategoryId="48">
            <Name language="en">Argentina</Name>
            <Tournament TournamentId="68" UniqueTournamentId="155">
                <Name language="en">Primera Division, Torneo Inicial</Name>
            </Tournament>
        </Category>
</Sport>`

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So, with the wording _". I want to select one specific Category node and his parent node (Sport) with one expression"_ you meant _"I want a sports node with only 1 category"_... which is an entirely different thing. Coming up...

Comment: Yes, that is true, sorry. But I do not know SportId, only CategoryId when selecting node.